# Is the addition property of equality valid for floating point numbers?

Tags: floating-point, precision, algebra

That is to say, if I have two floating point numbers (IEEE-754 binary floating-point) a and b, and I calculate c as follows:

```
c = a - b
```

Is this always true?

```
c + b == a
```

The answer to this simple question has been surprisingly difficult to find an answer to on the interwebs.  The closest thing I found was [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272990/1-s2.0-S1571066100X0151X/1-s2.0-S1571066104804080/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEID%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDDiQ5UaT7HFKbo4uSco9OdNaTCiXy6jNQpC5DfSWsoUwIgZZWG4vOToFBuxJNsrzrYMQCoKEIOpN6%2FDyUtMVAWF%2BwqtAMIeBADGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDBpv9sUXQsmYLt0wVSqRA93%2B3L35S6%2BPuD3XaUptMtzk2yRiUVmF%2BTPmhaXf70R8VqwiX6Cv83jguNlDPLM9hTHuWXdIK%2BuarVS9VhKwNVFbVaYGJuv3fJ7AQl5b45w%2BEGp37cKBFxrAdnqf4s6jNl7tzLA6lPtGEOXKL6gg2wPC4PvWVTqqKFpeb9374wuZc8f%2FxgR6jQOU2Jx72LqIewDZ7mHK%2BAiXmSDZ83cNMn4e8UYC4%2FomtDsPOqX1hlDck0pRZwk4YyQ123eYF5u%2BISrfX8S2zEegYf5FnF2FBBjrvdf8j89OnT8qI7Kj0z%2Fohb%2FiU28HUiPGTvJ4WiiIGlaTTurvGFGBImCKwWeCmGTxW5oh9lWQHD0o7b6H0RAIo9lgQfq8c5phy1I92uRAAZvX2IwLsRYnwFPBVp2%2FAaU1op3pUvPItKH0XO3llY3Q6T3%2BBGNnW6%2FIng%2BiYA5ayWCGB4zdhVAt0H9MUNXHYXF7A8iXOW7KyPjS84tlLuxBEPhWZjseGCJiMXERf762HUyfj4TQKwDTVyPx5jOyNVVbMNzLufoFOusBYYouXCSfCNoI5g8h73B5SGK7uQXEQ2lYRNQFrTIMEktVmEQeTRNN1XHE1djVsKYsrpeXualRABN8L56PQkKg%2FZRcBdx9xPF5ZcxDSkRVPKcN9SPIqFoAxwpgAbn3zmKEzMIfCdEzW%2B0GCGaOQCcThiTkSvP7NIaS4YVcXN65JFjMLJOS%2BzLyO2Kmu1QrBon46c%2FVN2h3IBwWxDHhbEU8UeioDBWA6FXUMMP9RzEstEUVljBu8v24I2OI%2Bfc8oIE5KbdxswWv53Bg4t11A%2BtAs6%2FUKwRaH%2FRDPA5zqCFx4Ky9vzEALpFs6copsQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200901T164341Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYWXLFMUG6%2F20200901%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=76f038184554e84975493d2be40fb4cefad6ad4deb3e1867bdf4fc6646f6cf2d&hash=e9095e5c58c5126eb36e45cb769c0aec76fcc951bbb9785bd85419d3e0be14d8&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S1571066104804080&tid=spdf-67ede010-8b04-4914-af94-64f6db331215&sid=1ea92aca612ac242874b4601d8bd0eb47231gxrqa&type=client).  Maybe I am simply not using the correct terminology.

Comment: What does the paper say?

Comment: That subtraction is exact under certain conditions ( I think).

Comment: Well, unless there is an open version of the paper around, I don't think it's fair to ask us to look at it.

Comment: I was able to download it.  Weird.

Comment: Your institution has a subscription.

Comment: From what I have seen, French researchers frequently deposit pre-prints of their papers in the INRIA online archive, and this is the case with the paper referenced in the question, which can be found [here](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072115).

Answer (score 5):

You definitely need to add some conditions excluding overflow. This java program prints "false".

```
public strictfp class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double b = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double c = a-b;
        System.out.println(c+b == a);
    }
}
```

`a-b` in real number arithmetic is twice the maximum finite double. In floating point arithmetic it overflows to infinity.

Comment: Is an overflow check all that is needed?

Comment: @Darko. Can you think of anything else? I'm fairly convinced that crossing scale boundaries is no problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am still thinking about the non-overflow issue. I am currently thinking about the round-half-even preference for even numbers with `a` odd.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan. Unless bitwise rounding gets weird when a and b are at different scales, I don't think there is an issue.

Comment: I am thinking of making `a` and `b` opposite sign, with `b` large magnitude, so there will be rounding on the difference, but you are probably right.

Answer (score 3):

My assumption is that the question pertains to computations with IEEE-754 binary floating-point arithmetic.

While tests cannot prove a hypothesized property, they can easily disprove one by finding counter examples. In this case we would not even need to go that far, as we can pick out a failing case by hand. Because IEEE-754 floating formats have finite precision, for non-zero `a` and `b` sufficiently different in magnitude with |`a`| < |`b`|, and in the absence of overflow and underflow, `c == -b`, then `c+b == 0 != a`.

The following simplistic ISO-C99 test program finds this and other cases:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

// Fixes via: Greg Rose, KISS: A Bit Too Simple. http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static unsigned int z=362436069,w=521288629,jsr=362436069,jcong=123456789;
#define znew (z=36969*(z&0xffff)+(z>>16))
#define wnew (w=18000*(w&0xffff)+(w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew)
#define SHR3 (jsr^=(jsr<<13),jsr^=(jsr>>17),jsr^=(jsr<<5)) /* 2^32-1 */
#define CONG (jcong=69069*jcong+13579)                     /* 2^32 */
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

float __uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

int main (void)
{
    const float ULMT = sqrtf (FLT_MAX) / 2; // avoid overflow
    const float LLMT = sqrtf (FLT_MIN) * 2; // avoid underflow
    const uint64_t N = 1ULL << 10;    
    uint64_t count = 0LL;
    uint32_t ai, bi;
    float af, bf, cf, sum;
   
    do {
        do {
            ai = KISS;
            af = __uint32_as_float (ai);
        } while (!isfinite(af) || (fabsf (af) > ULMT) || (fabsf (af) < LLMT));
        do {
            bi = KISS;
            bf = __uint32_as_float (bi);
        } while (!isfinite(bf) || (fabsf (bf) > ULMT) || (fabsf (bf) < LLMT));
        
        cf = af - bf;
        sum = cf + bf;
        if (sum != af) {
            printf ("a!=c+b:  a=% 15.6a  b=% 15.6a c=% 15.6a  b+c=% 15.6a\n", 
                    af, bf, cf, sum);
        }
        count++;
    } while (count < N);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```